# Rails - include module : If we include multiple modules to class/controller will it affect memory or perfomance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just trying to find is there any difference in performance / memory usage when we include lot of modules to classes (mostly are not used) ?

```rb
class FirstController < ApplicationController
  def helo
    'first class'
  end
end

class SecondController < ApplicationController
  include SomeBigModule
  def helo
    'second class'
  end
end

module SomeBigModule
  include OtherBigModule
  include AnotherBigModule
  # lot of methods here
  # here too...
end
```

So, in the above case I have two controllers, both having a helo method. But the second class (SecondController) includes lot of other modules. So will there be any difference in perfomance/memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it. You have bigger fish to fry.

Including a module does not copy all the methods of a module to a class when include it. Instead it adds the module to the ancestors chain. There is a slight cost involved in finding the method in the ancestors chain but its extremely insignificant.

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  module Greeter
    def hello
      "Hello World!"
    end
  end

  class A
    include Greeter
  end

  class B
    def hello
      "Hello World!"
    end
  end

  a = A.new
  b = B.new

  x.report('module method:') do
    (10**6).times { a.hello }
  end

  x.report('instance method:') do
    (10**6).times { b.hello }
  end
end
```

```
       user     system      total        real
module method:  0.208063   0.000000   0.208063 (  0.217949)
instance method:  0.203745   0.000000   0.203745 (  0.214142)
```

Its not like you're ever going to be calling a method 1 million times during the processing of a request unless something is seriously broken.

If we are talking about memory usage its also insignificant. In production Rails will eager_load all the classes/modules in its eager load paths (such as `/app`) at startup so it does not actually matter if you're referencing the constants in your controller or not. And since each module is really just a reference in the ancestors chain including multiple modules does not actually increase memory usage to any significant degree.

What you really should be worrying about instead are the design implications of splitting your code into a large amount of modules that are included in a single object. That is a sign that the object may be doing way to much. Performance wise you really should be more worried about SQL queries and caching which is where you can make a large difference.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a small not noticeable difference in memory usage (unless we're talking about thousands of methods), and there shouldn't be any difference in performance, except when starting your Rails app if the modules are really huge.

Modules, as well as Classes in Ruby are constants, and loaded in memory upon require (or in the case of Rails when booting). Once the code is loaded there won't be any difference in executing the method on an instance of the first controller vs the second controller.

Comment: The last part depends on `Rails.config.eager_load`. With the default rails settings Rails will eager load all everything in the eager load paths in production but not in development.